# Arduino to check if digital connected to analog

Tags: arduino-uno

Is it possible to check if a Analog pin is touching a digital?
I have an Arduino Uno, and I want to have a small matrix, A0 A1 A2 A3 (all have rows of 6 buttons)
All the 6 buttons are connected to the digital pins
This is how I want it to work

```
Digital (1,2,3,4,5,6)
(A0)1,2,3,4,5,6
(A1)1,2,3,4,5,6
(A2)1,2,3,4,5,6
(A3)1,2,3,4,5,6
```

I've tried writing code but for each key pressed it gives the same value for each row i.e it's not detecting different sections.

Comment: https://playground.arduino.cc/code/keypad

Comment: please post your code so that we can check for errors